# force function to use value of variable

Tags: javascript

HELP on javascript
force function to use the value of variable and not the variable name

```
var a = 12;
var b = 13;

element.setAttribute("onChange","calculate('a','b')");

calculate(x,y){

z = x + y;
alert(z)

}
```

how to pass value of variable to be use in function?

Comment: Do you want to use the values of `a` and `b` at the time you configure the `onchange` handler, or at the time the handler is called? Also, event handler names are case-sensitive, it should be `"onchange"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" id="cb">​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function calculate(x, y) {
    var z = x + y;
    alert(z);
}

var a = 12,
    b = 13,
    element = document.getElementById('cb');

element.onchange = function(e) {
    calculate(a, b);
};​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/3pbxp/)**

Also consider the usage of [element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

'a' is not the variable `a`.  It's the string 'a'.  if you want the variable, take the quotes off.

Answer (score 0):

`.setAttribute("onChange","calculate(" + a + "," + b +")");`